# How to override the text-overflow in a slide animation in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm a complete rookie at 'CSS' and I want to come up with a simple animation based on a text slide. The issue is that I can't get over with this situation when I shorten the container or make the browser smaller the slide cuts off part of the text and it's not the case wrapping.

I tried different variants of overflow and animation-duration.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <p>
    <img class="logo" src="picture.png" width="80" height="80" align='left'>
    <div id="marquee">
       <div id="text">some text string exceeding the container</div>
    </div>
  </body>                  
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes slide {
from {
    left: 100%;
}
to {
    left: -100%;
}
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
from {
    left: 100%;
}
to {
    left: -100%;
}
}

#marquee {
color: #FE5501;
background: #111;
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
line-height: 80px;
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
top: 10px;
left: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
}

#text {
position: absolute;
font-family: "Consolas";
display: inline-block;
top: 0;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
font-size: 40px;
animation-name: slide;
animation-duration: 5s;
animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-name: slide;
-webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I would really kile to get a design where next to the logo I would have a an animation that could display a long text so that I could use this in a nice 'ui'.

Comment: https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/ take a look at  `text-overflow`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for a quick reply but none of the below helped:
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: clip;
 white-space: nowrap;
The flowing string gets cut depending on the the width of the browser / container although the position is absolute

Comment: You missed an important one, `text-overflow: ellipsis` It adds a `...` at the end of the string and hides the overflowing text from the view

Comment: Yes... I have tested this but I do not aim to have the dots but the full text looping through the container infinitely but thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want to do I think you just need to set a fixed width to your marquee div.

For example :

```
width: calc(100vw - 120px);
```

see the codepen here : https://codepen.io/marc-simplon/pen/xoKYbJ?editors=1100

Edit:

The issue was with your 'width: 100%', because **%** is a *relative* unit, relative to the **parent** element. So you need to have a parent element with a fixed size. Therefore this (for example), also works :

```
body {
    width: 100vw;
}

#marquee {
width: 50%;
}
```

Edit 2:

After CorpoKillsMe's comment, I modified the live demo provided to make the entire title slide in the container's defined width.

See : https://codepen.io/marc-simplon/pen/OeLwZv?editors=1100

- I removed the `position: absolute` attribute and the related attributes (top, etc) of the #text selector.
- Then I use `transform: translate(-100%);` instead of left in the keyframe.
- And the important modification : I removed the width attribute in the #text selector

(It would have work with the position: absolute and left trick, but I think the transform solution's more elegant)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've tried out your solution but id doesn't work for me. I need the text container to be exactly 310px wide and when I set this parameter the slide ends too early and it's being cut. I need it to be quite small as it is  gong to serve as a gui in python.

Comment: Can we see a live demo?

Comment: https://codepen.io/CorpoKillsMe/pen/XLrqNN
I want to make the window and the animation small because I will put it in the QtWebEngine on PySide2

Comment: Hey. Thanks a lot. This looks way better than what I came up with from patching up things from the web. I know that I'm asking maybe too much but is it even possible to achieve an effect that this animation would run smoothly like the whole text runs and hides on the left but then appears gradually from the right? Right now it sure is working without interruption but the starting point is that the whole text just appears in the container suddenly and then does the slide. Could you help me with this last stage? pls

Comment: Hey I just realized that I can modify this:
from {
     transform: translate(100%);
Thank you for your time and help. Cheers!

Comment: Meanwhile I had updated the codepen to make the slide smoother, if you want to look at it.

Comment: Works like charm ;-) Thanks